# install mongodb on centos 6.5 + nginx

Tags: mongodb, nginx, centos

I follow the mongodb website tried to install on my machine centos 6.5 + nginx, 
after below step when I run `service mongod start` shows `Starting mongod [FAILED]`

```
vi /etc/yum.repos.d/mongodb-org-3.0.repo


yum install mongodb-org
```

var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

```
2015-09-07T20:46:32.757+0800 I CONTROL  ***** SERVER RESTARTED *****
2015-09-07T20:46:32.861+0800 E NETWORK  [initandlisten] Failed to unlink socket file /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock errno:1 Operation not permitted
2015-09-07T20:46:32.861+0800 I -        [initandlisten] Fatal Assertion 28578
2015-09-07T20:46:32.861+0800 I -        [initandlisten] 

***aborting after fassert() failure
```

vi ../etc/mongod.conf
 ( I have not yet change anything in `mongod.conf`)

```
# mongod.conf

#where to log
logpath=/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

logappend=true

# fork and run in background
fork=true

#port=27017

dbpath=/var/lib/mongo

# location of pidfile
pidfilepath=/var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid

# Listen to local interface only. Comment out to listen on all interfaces.
bind_ip=127.0.0.1

# Disables write-ahead journaling
# nojournal=true

# Enables periodic logging of CPU utilization and I/O wait
#cpu=true

# Turn on/off security.  Off is currently the default
#noauth=true
#auth=true

# Verbose logging output.
#verbose=true

# Inspect all client data for validity on receipt (useful for
# developing drivers)
#objcheck=true

# Enable db quota management
#quota=true

# Set oplogging level where n is
#   0=off (default)
#   1=W
#   2=R
#   3=both
#   7=W+some reads
#diaglog=0

# Ignore query hints
#nohints=true

# Enable the HTTP interface (Defaults to port 28017).
#httpinterface=true

# Turns off server-side scripting.  This will result in greatly limited
# functionality
#noscripting=true

# Turns off table scans.  Any query that would do a table scan fails.
#notablescan=true

# Disable data file preallocation.
#noprealloc=true

# Specify .ns file size for new databases.
# nssize=<size>

# Replication Options

# in replicated mongo databases, specify the replica set name here
#replSet=setname
# maximum size in megabytes for replication operation log
#oplogSize=1024
# path to a key file storing authentication info for connections
# between replica set members
#keyFile=/path/to/keyfile
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try deleting this file : `/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock`

After that just restart service :)

Comment: Its a listening socket file that allows local connections to the MongoDB without having to spawn a TCP/UDP connection. It should be removed when you stop Mongo automatically and will be created when it starts.

Answer (score 0):

Bringing this back from the dead a bit.

The user which runs mongod needs permission to the /tmp directory. To avoid this, there's a config setting you can apply which changes where the mongodb-.sock file is created. The user already has access to their home folder, so this worked for me.

```
net:
  port: 27017
  unixDomainSocket:
    pathPrefix: /home/vagrant/config0
```